# Existence of covers of curves in characteristic $p$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

For a given smooth curve over $\mathbb{C}$ and $n$ ramification profiles (which each sum up to a fixed degree $d$), by considering monodromy representations the existence problem of such covers can be reduced to some representation theory of the symmetric group $S_d$. This is for example described in "Riemann Surfaces and Algebraic Curves : A First Course in Hurwitz Theory" by Cavalieri and Miles.

In the case of positive characteristic, I could not find any similar result, which tells me what kind of covers do exist. Is there any result in this direction that provides some examples of Hurwitz covers in positive characteristic, preferable also in the wild case, maybe using étale fundamental groups or similar techniques?